# commenting vs answering

Tags: support, comments

So I went to comment on an easy  question and it said that " I needed a reputation of 50 to comment" but I could still answer the question ?!? Sometimes it's hard as I need to ask the user more questions to give a definite answer so I guess what I'm saying is I really don't understand the concept of how this system works?

Answer (score 5):

From [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

> Answers don't have to be exhaustive or infallible, they just need to try to answer the question. It's perfectly fine to post an answer saying, for example, "I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but if it's X, you can solve it by doing Y. If that doesn't help, try Z and let me know what it says." Also, if further information does become available, you can edit your answer later to make it more precise.

So, answer to the best of your ability.  Your answer will also show up in the First Posts queue, which give it more exposure for upvoting (assuming it is a good answer).